# Multiplot with different scales in sympy or matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plot, sympy

How can I multiplot into the same subplot, with different scales on the axis?

```
from sympy import *
x=Symbol('x')
plot_sin = plot( (sin(x),(x, -2*pi, 2*pi)))
plot_cos10 = plot( (cos(x)*10,(x, -2*pi, 2*pi)))
```

Result:

[image]

Both plots must be in the same plot. But the second plot has a range from -10 to 10 on the y-Axis. So in real, there must be two y-Axis. Maybe one in blue on the left side from -1 to 1 and a second one on the right side in red from -10 to 10. Is this possible? If not with sympy, maybe with matplotlib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is adapted from an example on [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/api/two_scales.html) and sounds to me to be very similar to what you are looking for.

### Solution

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
s1 = np.sin(x)
ax1.plot(x, s1, 'b-')
ax1.set_xlabel('time (s)')
# Make the y-axis label, ticks and tick labels match the line color.
ax1.set_ylabel('sin(x)', color='b')
ax1.tick_params('y', colors='b')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
s2 = np.cos(x)
ax2.plot(x, s2, 'r.')
ax2.set_ylabel('cos(x)*10', color='r')
ax2.tick_params('y', colors='r')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

### Output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA0uk.png)

Comment: exactly. That is a good example for two scales. Thank you!

Comment: btw, you have to change the 't' with 'x' inside the two plot commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can `plot` multiple line plots together such as below example.

```py
from sympy import *
x=Symbol('x')

plot( (sin(x),(x, -2*pi, 2*pi)), (cos(x)*10,(x, -2*pi, 2*pi)))
```

[image: Output]

What do you mean 2 different `y-axis` ? I can update my answer accordingly if you think i misunderstood your question.

Comment: Hello Jay. Sorry, in my case I want to display plots with different scales and units to compare them. All have a equal x-axis, but the value is different. My fault, that I haven't explained correct. Look at the answer from charles.